# Render single Object / Mesh immediatly into a renderTarget

Tags: three.js

I need to render a single specific mesh from a scene into a texture using a THREE.WebGLRenderTarget. I already achieved that during the rendering of the scene, all other meshes, except this one, are being ignored. So, I basically achieved my goal. The thing i hate is, that there is still a lot of unnecessary work going on for my whole scene graph, during the render process of the scene. I need to render this texture every frame, so with my current method i get extrem fps drop downs. (There are lots of meshes in the whole scene graph).

So what i found was the function "renderBufferImmediate" from the THREE.WebGLRenderer. (Link to the renderer source code [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js)) My pseudo code to achieve my goal would look like this:

```
var mesh = some_Mesh;
var renderer = some_WebGLRenderer;
var renderTarget = some_WebGLRenderTarget;

renderer.setRenderTarget(renderTarget);
var materialProperties = renderer.properties.get(mesh.material);
var program = materialProperties.program;
renderer.renderBufferImmediate(mesh, program, mesh.material);

var texture = renderTarget.texture;
```

The renderBufferImmediate function takes an instance of an THREE.Object3D, a WebGLShaderProgram and a THREE.Material. Problem i see here: The implementation of this function tries to lookup properties of the Object3D which, afaik doesn't exist. (Like "hasPositions" or "hasNormals"). In short: my approach doesn't work.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me if i can use this function for my purpose (Meaning i am currently using it wrong) or if there is another solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This cannot be done easily.

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14476

Comment: Just for reference, `Object3D` is a base-class for a slew of other classes, including `Group` and `Mesh`, so you could pass either of the latter two into an `Object3D` parameter and be okay.